# Sublime Text 3 indentation driving me nuts

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 as my code editor. I would like some help/explanation as to why the indentation misbehaves so much:

- Is there any way to force the indentation when you open a file (I like it set to tabs, tabs_size = 4)?
- Whenever I save a file, it automatically reverts the indentation to spaces... How would one go about avoiding that?

Any help is appreciated, I've been pulling my hair because of these tiny issues.

P.S.: Here are my settings

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/base16-ocean.dark (SL).tmTheme",
    "detect_indentation": false,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "font_face": "Source Code Pro",
    "font_size": 15.0,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "SideBarEnhancements",
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "theme": "Spacegray.sublime-theme",
    "word_wrap": true
}
```